# How to save different surveys to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, relational-database, database-schema

I'm assigned to make a web based survey  application on ASP.NET MVC3.
And I have three different surveys. I have to the way best way to store survey answers on database. I'm came up with only one solution: To make an answer table for each survey type.

Can you suggest better solutions?

Comment: Yes, there are better solutions. Read up on normalizing database tables. One answer table should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have single table itself for Answers with **Survey type** as a Column.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this?

table survey_answers

id (this is the pk) : qid (question id):  answer (varchar MAX) : pid (person id)

what you can do with this is make a questions table, a person table. in the question table, put the qid, the question, and the group of questions it belongs to (the survey id). Persons table is obvious, you put a pid (person id) and info about the person (such as name, age, gender etc.)

the reason that a three table approach is bad is because let's say the amount of surveys you have grows. let's see it becomes 100 different types of surveys or more - which is a definite possibility depending on where you work - are you going to have 100 different tables? 1000? no way.